setting IAP with GKE: error code 11 but no obvious reason
I configured IAP for my GKE web app but I am getting this error message: There was a problem with your request. Please reference https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq#error_codes. Error code 11
I checked the page, but I already have my client ID and secrets configured to my cluster.
apiVersion: v1
data:
  client_id: BASE64_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret: BASE64_CLIENT_SECRET
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: stg-oauth-secret
type: Opaque
--
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: stg-web-default
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: stg-oauth-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "stg-web-default"}'
  name: stg-web
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: web
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: stg-web-default
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: stg-oauth-secret
---
# ...

Also, the OAuth Consent screen has my web app's domain in Authorized Domain.
What else do I need to check?

Have you checked this and also check this another SO question where turning IAP on and off will solve the issue.

I have tried turning on and off, waiting more than 1 day, recreating secrets etc. none of them change the situation

After reading specifically this comment of a previous SO question, turning the IAP off and then on again was indeed the fix. However there were a few pointers I was not aware of: simply deleting the BackendConfig and removing the annotation from the Service does not seem to make a previously enabled IAP off. The most reliable way to turn IAP off is to go to the IAP page on the console, and turn off the switch as shown below.

After the switch is off, it takes a few minutes for the change to propagate on your browser, so you need to wait until your browser stops showing the Google login page.
